# "thing.appendChild is not a function" for object method

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

Apologies for the horrific title; <del>I'm unsure how to summarise this problem in such few characters.</del>

**TL;DR** Why doesn't `$("#canvas").appendChild()` work?

I have a prototype `Car` which, on instantiation, is supposed to create a div inside a div whose id is "canvas".

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var canvas = $("#canvas");

    function Car(speed) {
        ...        
        this.domDiv = document.createElement("div");
        $(this.domDiv).addClass("car");
        this.addToCanvas = function() {
            canvas.appendChild(this.domDiv);
        };
        this.addToCanvas();
        ...
    }

    car1 = new Car(0.5);

});
```

However, I get `Uncaught TypeError: canvas.appendChild is not a function`, and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct function is append, rather than appendChild on a jQuery wrapper

```
canvas.append(this.domDiv);
```

You would want to use appendChild if you used a host query selector (document.getElementById('canvas')) rather than a jQuery selector ($('canvas'))

Answer (score 2):

`appendChild` is a DOM function. `append` is a jQuery function (canvas is a jQuery object).